# How to run an indicator on a particular timaeframe and particular chart on Pinescript v5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have an indicator for Tradingview but I need this indicator to be displayed only in a single chart let's say 'TSLA' and in a single timeframe (Daily). What should I add to the code?

Also, is it possible if anyone opens the indicator on a different chart or timeframe, a text reminder shows up on the bottom of the screen?

I tried to use syminfo.ticker command but I couldn't make it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try [syminfo.ticker](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_syminfo.ticker) and [timeframe.period](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_timeframe.period)
   Something like that:

`colorPlot = syminfo.ticker == 'TSLA' and timeframe.period == 'D' ? color.new(color.blue, 0) : na plot(close , 'close' , color = colorPlot)`

2. Try *f_tfReminderAndErrorCheck* from [this library](https://www.tradingview.com/script/00jFIl5w-security-revisited-PineCoders/)